# DC power consumption versus input power of RF amplifier

Tags: power, amplifier

I am trying to understand the DC power power consumption of an RF amplifier versus the input signal power. Is there a dependence between the power consumption of an RF amplifier and the power of an input signal?

Comment: Yes there is generally a dependency at RF (not so much at lower frequencies of course).

Comment: There can be but it's not necessary, and it's easier to call out if you're talking about amplification stages inside a schematic rather than something like a multi-stage lab amplifier.  Can you _edit your question_ with an example of a specific schematic?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a dependence between the power consumption of an RF amplifier
> and the power of an input signal?

Yes, of course.

The irradiated RF power comes from the DC power supply.

The percentage of DC power converted into RF power depends solely on the Class/Topology of the RF amplifier and it's called PAE:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-added_efficiency

---

A good RF amplifier has a PAE of 50%

---

An old but widely used RF amplifier topology of 4G and 5G base stations is Doherty's:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doherty_amplifier

Answer (score 0):

As Enrico Migliore's answer states, yes there is. Picture a time-varying signal at the gate of a transistor in an amplifier, as its amplitude varies, the drain current will be modulated. This current has to come from the supply to the drain. We often assume amplifiers, aside from Power Amplifiers, are operating in the small-signal region, where this variation is negligible but it is always there.

From a DC power consumption point of view, what matters in the situation described above is the average drain current. Say you input a continuous sine wave of a given amplitude, this will demand some average drain current. If you increase the amplitude of the sine wave, the average drain current and hence DC power consumption will increase.

Sometimes amplifier datasheets will even show you how the supply current varies with input power, such as the curve shown below from the datasheet for Analog Devices' ADL8106 amplifier. For small input powers you can see that the supply current Idd doesn't change much, but it rapidly increases once we start to leave small-signal operation.

[image]

Watch out if you have an input signal with a time-varying envelope, such as a pulse train or a AM waveform; your power supply will have to provide a time-varying supply current, meaning that your bias network needs to have sufficient bandwidth to let the envelope bandwidth pass through.